# How can I install a Mac provisioning profile in AzureDevops?

Tags: macos, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, provisioning-profile

We have previously been using the "Install Apple Provisioning Profile" task in our Azure Pipeline build to install a Mac provisioning profile `*.provisionprofile`. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-apple-provisioning-profile?view=azure-devops)

However, as of today the build is failing during the `Pre-job` step with the following error:

```
##[error]Error: Provisioning profile file should have the extension '.mobileprovision'
```

Having checked, I don't think that we've changed anything to affect this, so I was wondering if this is an outside change to the step, and if anyone knows of a work-around?

(For mobile development the provisioning profile file would be `*.mobileprovision`, but the Mac development ones aren't so I don't know if changing the file extension would work?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted the question here too on the Azure pipelines tasks github (related to the `InstallAppleProvisioningProfileV1` task): https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/13104

It looks like the issue has been fixed already in their repository, and we need to wait to get the next update.

I'll update the reply if the instructions change at all, but it looks like we may get the fix on the next release.